# How to populate this form data and post it with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a html form as follows:-

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="" id="scheduler_form">{%csrf_token%}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="url" class="col-sm-3 control-label">URL</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="url" name="url" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="reporttemplate" class="col-sm-3 control-label">SELECT REPORT TEMPLATE</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select name="report_template_id" id="report_list_sel" class="form-control" data-placeholder="Choose a Template" required="required"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="frequency" class="col-sm-3 control-label">FREQUENCY</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <label class="radio-inline" for="inlineRadio1">
                <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="inlineRadio1" value="hourly" checked="checked">Hourly</label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="inlineRadio2" value="Daily">Daily</label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="inlineRadio3" value="Weekly">Weekly</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">EMAIL</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <label for="alerts" class="col-sm-3 control-label" style="padding-right:23px">ALERTS</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="checkbox col-sm-offset-3" id="alert_list" style="height:100px;overflow-y:auto"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" id="create_schedule">CREATE</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right closediv" data-dismiss="setup_blk" aria-label="Close">CANCEL</button>
</form>
```

I have a generic method to make an Ajax call.

```
function makeAJAXRequest(_uri, _method, _data, _contenttype, _datatype, _context, _processdata, _successHandler, _errorHandler){
  var _jqXHR = $.ajax({
    url: _uri,
    type: _method,
    data: _data,
    contentType: _contenttype,
    dataType: _datatype,
    context: _context,
    processData: _processdata,
    cache: true
  });
  _jqXHR.done( _successHandler );
  _jqXHR.fail( _errorHandler );
}
```

Now I am binding `create_schedule` button as follows.

```
 $('#create_schedule').on('click', function (event) {
     // Call a function createScheduler to build json data for AJAX - POST call and get response.
     createScheduler();
 });

 function createScheduler() {
     var _schedulerData = {};
     $.each($('#scheduler_form'), function () {
         _schedulerData[this.name] = this.value;
         console.log(_schedulerData);
     });

     makeAJAXRequest(
     API_SCHEDULE,
         'post', _schedulerData,
         '',

         'json', {},

     true,
     createUserScheduleSuccessHandler,
     createUserScheduleErrorHandler);

     function createUserScheduleSuccessHandler(_data) {
         console.log(_data);
     }

     function createUserScheduleErrorHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log('Error')
     }

 }
```

Now I am getting confused as how to populate the form data and make the post request. Any help here.

Comment: Not 110% sure, but by clicking your submit button you will REFRESH the page, therefore you will not perform any ajax request. To fix that, you can either **prevent the submit default event** or change the submit button to a regular button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" .... >
```

To

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" .....>
```

OR:

you can call the `prevenDefault` method when button click fired.

```
event.preventDefault();
console.log( $( '.form-horizontal' ).serialize() );
```

[serializing](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form will get all the data from `form` controls.

Comment: Ok but how to collect that data on the JS in the `createScheduler` method. The ajax request gets made in the createScheduler method

Comment: It worked but gives me data as `url=http%3A%2F%2Fin.strawberrynet.com%2Fmain.aspx&frequency=hourly&email=rokumar%40gmail.com` . I have to parse the data into json format for the ajax call.

Comment: yeah ...you need to serialize this as object. Use: `$('.form-horizontal').serializeObject();` see the github api: https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object

Comment: Yes but it will not be serializeObject , it will be serializeJSON() . Thanks